# jQuery element manipulation won't refresh the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, refresh

I've written a jQuery plugin for practice which was supposed to work like ["Airport" by unwrongest](http://unwrongest.com/projects/airport/).

**Short description of how it should operate**

1. Get the text of some element, iterate through it.
2. For every char found, iterate through the alphabet, comparing the
   char with each char in the alphabet...
3. ...until text-char = alphabet-char (or until the "alphabet"-array has no more elements.
4. While comparing, change the actual text with a certain delay.

So for example, using the plugin on hi would change the word from hi (start) to ai, bi, ci, [...], ha, hb, hc, hd, [...], hi, sort of flipping through it. Again, if you have no clue what I mean, you could check the link.

**Problem**

Checking the console with firebug, it does change the target text, ***but it just doesn't update till it has reached the end***. First I thought it didnt do anything at all, but when I change the code to turn each character into an "A" (as an example), it updates the text to "AAAAAAAA" at the very end. What I need the plugin to do, though, is of course update it after every single change.

**The code**

```
(function( $ ){

  $.fn.myAirport = function() {
        var text = this.text();
        var length = text.length;
        var alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "!", "?"];
        var possibilities = alphabet.length;

        function changeCharAt(string, index, char) {
            var length = string.length;
            if(index > length-1) return string;

            var before = string.substr(0,index);
            var after = string.substr(index+1);
            result = before + char + after;
            return result;
        }



        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            var letter = text[i];
            console.log("looking for: "+letter);

            for (var j = 0; j < possibilities; j++) {
                var test = alphabet[j];
                if (letter == test) {
                    console.log("Done, "+letter+" (letter # "+i+") is # "+j+" in the Alphabet-string");
                    j = possibilities;
                }
                else {}

                text = changeCharAt(text, i, test);
                $(this).text(text).delay(100);              
                console.log("Trying "+$(this).text());
            }
        }
  };
})( jQuery );
```

The plugin is called like this: `$("#element").myAirport();`

Comment: I'd suggest just going throughout the Airport plugin source code http://jquery-airport.googlecode.com/files/jquery.airport-1.1.source.js and see how your code differs from that, or do you want to do something different from what they've done?

Comment: I actually dont want to use it at all. ;) It's mainly practice. I also checked the code and compared, but didn't find an obvious mistake. Also, because it's supposed to be pracice, Im trying to change as little as possible in my code. After all, I want to make mine work! :)

Comment: i understand but looking at what they did should help you understand what you are doing better: see one, do one, teach one

Answer (score 0):

Browsers tend to wait until for loops to complete before update. Rather than using

```
 $(this).text(text).delay(100)
```

try a setTimeout function.

[How do I make an HTML element repaint within a Javascript loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584370/how-do-i-make-an-html-element-repaint-within-a-javascript-loop)